# error while removing network: <network> id has active endpoints

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, containers

I am trying run docker compose down using jenkins job.
"sudo docker-compose down --remove-orphans"

I have used --remove-orphans command while using the docker-compose down.
Still it gives below error.

Removing network. abc
error while removing network: network  id ************ has active endpoints
Failed command  with status 1: sudo docker-compose down --remove-orphans

Below is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  abc:
    image: <img>
    container_name: 'abc'
    hostname: abc
    ports:
      - "5****:5****"
      - "1****:1***"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/<volume>
    networks:
      - <network>

      
  container-app-1:
    image: <img2>
    container_name: 'container-app-1'
    hostname: 'container-app-1'
    depends_on:
      - abc
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    env_file: ./.env
    networks:
      - <network>

networks:
  <network>:
    driver: bridge
    name: <network>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To list your networks, run `docker network ls`. You should see your `<network>` there. Then get the containers still attached to that network with (replacing your network name at the end of the command):

```
docker network inspect \
  --format '{{range $cid,$v := .Containers}}{{printf "%s: %s\n" $cid $v.Name}}{{end}}' \
  "<network>"
```

For the various returned container id's, you can check why they haven't stopped (inspecting the logs, making sure they are part of the compose project, etc), or manually stop them if they aren't needed anymore with (replacing the `<cid>` with your container id):

```
docker container stop "<cid>"
```

Then you should be able to stop the compose project.

Comment: is this one time job and i have to run these manually because I am running the docker compose down job using jenkins pipeline

Comment: @knowledge20 this can be easily automated, there's no need to output both the container name and ID in that format string. But I'd start with figuring out why there are other containers on that network. Is it because you've specified the name and used an existing network name? Is it because there are multiple runs of the pipeline, and you didn't make the network unique for each?

Comment: we had multiple runs with same network but the pipeline first stge is docker compose down. so it should not create any problems I hope. The first stage is failing every time

Comment: @knowledge20 does this mean you aren't willing to run the commands to debug your problem?

Comment: Yes..I have faced this issue for the first time...I am not sure if this will be appear again and again..I want to add either a permament fix or some script so thhat this error doesnt come up again.\

Answer (score 20):

There is a situation when there are no containers at all, but there is an error. Then `systemctl restart docker` helped me

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen, when you have a db instance running on separate container and using the same network. In this case, removing the db instance using the command

```
docker container stop "<cid>"
```

will stop the container. We can find the container id that is using the network by using the command provided by @BMitch

```
docker network inspect \
  --format '{{range $cid,$v := .Containers}}{{printf "%s: %s\n" $cid $v.Name}}{{end}}' \
  "<network>"
```

But in my case, when I did that, it also made that postgres instance "orphaned". Then i did

```
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

After that, I booted up a new db instance (postgres) using docker compose file and mapped the volume of data directory of that to the data directory of the previous db instance.

```
    volumes:
      - './.docker/postgres/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/'
      - ~/backup/postgress:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use:

```bash
$ docker network disconnect <network> <container>
```

to disconnect problematic container (if you know its name) from the network, as per: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#disconnect-a-container-from-a-user-defined-bridge:

> To disconnect a running container from a user-defined bridge, use the docker network disconnect command.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was solved only by restarting the docker and then deleting the container manually from the docker desktop.